# Exclude local hash links from executing AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, anchor

I've got a website in development with new pages loaded via AJAX instead of traditional page loads. Most links on the site will use AJAX to load a new page, however there are some links I need to exclude from this behaviour. For example, local hash links that simply scroll you down to an anchor on the same page. Or, links to PDF files that are hosted locally but should obviously not be loaded via AJAX. I have enough control over the HTML that I can simply add a class to these links that I want to exclude, such as .local-anchor, or .pdf. The code I have effectively excludes these links if you directly load the page the first time, however any time the page is loaded via AJAX my exclusion no longer works. The .local-anchor links and any others that should be excluded are still somehow executing the AJAX functions. Example of the relevant JS code:

```
$(document).on("click", "a:not('.local-anchor, .pdf')", function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    // check that it points to this domain
    if ( href.indexOf(document.domain) > -1 || href.indexOf(':') === -1 ) {
      history.pushState({}, '', href);
      loadPage(href);
      e.stopPropagation(); 
      e.preventDefault();
    } 
  });
```

**You can see this live page (in development) here:** http://dma.nz/practice/

The links:

Our approach to design
The architectural process
Awards + Publications
Contact

Scroll you to anchors further down the same page and should be excluded. Yet if this page is loaded via AJAX (test by navigating to one of the other main nav links on top right and then return to Practice) then these links are triggering AJAX to reload this same page which screws things up.

How do I need to amend this JS to make sure they are ALWAYS excluded?

Comment: Live page not accessible

Comment: @snit80 sorry fixed now live page should work

Comment: @anied for this particular use they can be omitted completely. There is another function specifically targetting them to trigger a velocity.js page scroll to the local anchor when they are clicked. For triggering AJAX I definitely always want them excluded.

Comment: Sorry, removed that comment-- once you got the live site up I loaded it and realized I had misunderstood the question.

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts here? I need this to go live soon and I can't seem to get past this problem.